# How to Cascade Changes if Insert New Row as Update Method?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table with fields PK, Username, DOB, etc, Status. If I change the username, I do not update the original row but instead insert a new row with the original information with the new username and I set the old row status=0. (So I do not delete any information). How can I update tables that had the old row pk as a foreign key to the pk of the new row? I do not think On Casacade would work.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. A primary key should remain static throughout the life of a given record. I'd push back on whatever business requirement is causing you to create a new primary key just because a username is updated.

Comment: how would you keep track of changes then?

Comment: @user1406416: This is commonly done using triggers and audit tables. Try [this search](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=018205968162215846785%3A7n6ajnwyz-i&ie=UTF-8&q=sql+server+audit+table&sa=Search).

Answer (score 1):

Agree with A primary key should remain static throughout the life of a given record!  Implement a username history table and update the username in the original table.  Insert the PK as a FK into the history table with changes.  You have a new table tracking the changes and your original table is there to serve its purpose, still relating to the other tables as it should.

Comment: If you do this, you should also create a view that is a union of the two tables, so you can query that easily when you want all the historical records.